# How to solve "You must NOT be root to run crosstool-NG" when using ct-ng?

Tags: c, cross-compiling

when I follow the steps here to create a cross complie env, [http://crosstool-ng.org/
]

I got such an error:

```
root@gpl-vm:~# ct-ng build
[ERROR]  You must NOT be root to run crosstool-NG
[00:00] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

When I switch to a common user, it says I have no right to perform the command.

Comment: You should start over as the user from the beginning... You have files there which only root can access so you can't run anything. But ct-ng doesn't run as root.

Answer (score 9):

**`CT_ALLOW_BUILD_AS_ROOT=y`**

As of d5900debd397b8909d9cafeb9a1093fb7a5dc6e6 (Jun 2018) that option allows you to allow you to build as root if you really know what you are doing:

```
CT_EXPERIMENTAL=y
CT_ALLOW_BUILD_AS_ROOT=y
CT_ALLOW_BUILD_AS_ROOT_SURE=y
```

They can accessed on the menus from:

- Paths and misc options

  - Try features marked as EXPERIMENTAL

    - Allow building as root user (READ HELP!)

      - Are you sure?

However, I would recommend you to read the help for that option carefully:

```
  │ You normally do *not* need to be root to build a toolchain using                                                                                                                                           │  
  │ crosstool-NG. In fact, it is *VERY* dangerous to run as root, as                                                                                                                                           │  
  │ crosstool-NG will, as part of the build process, remove a few                                                                                                                                              │  
  │ directories. If anything goes wrong, running as root can ruin                                                                                                                                              │  
  │ your host distribution.                                                                                                                                                                                    │  
  │                                                                                                                                                                                                            │  
  │ I can't stress it enough:  DO  NOT  RUN  AS  ROOT  !!                                                                                                                                                      │  
  │                                                                                                                                                                                                            │  
  │ Do not run as root, you've been warned.                                                                                                                                                                    │  
  │ Do not come whining, if it nukes your host system.                                                                                                                                                         │  
  │ Do not come whining, if you lose any data.                                                                                                                                                                 │  
  │ Do not run as root.                                                                                                                                                                                        │  
  │                                                                                                                                                                                                            │  
  │ Do not run as root, you've been warned.                                                                                                                                                                    │  
  │ Do not come whining, if the Earth stops rotating.                                                                                                                                                          │  
  │ Do not come whining, if kittens are smashed.                                                                                                                                                               │  
  │ Do not run as root.                                                                                                                                                                                        │  
  │                                                                                                                                                                                                            │  
  │ Do not run as root, do not run as root!                                                                                                                                                                    │  
  │ (ad libitum)                                                                                                                                                                                               │  
  │
```

Maybe the most acceptable use case for this is to run crosstool-NG run within Docker as [I'm doing here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/7a5ca339a356fff98c1537f0b2c5e960757924d8#docker). It works.

Found by grepping the error message in the source code :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use **root** user. To build it, use **a normal user**.

Try

```
# adduser crosstoolng
# chown crosstoolng:crosstoolng <crosstool-path>
# su crosstoolng
$ ./ct-ng build
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build ct-ng as root. You need to allow that explicitly and confirm in menuconfig. There is an entry in paths and misc options.

Comment: For those who also have trouble finding this option: you need to enable `Try features marked as EXPERIMENTAL` to see it.

Answer (score 0):

It does not run under the user gut, run as a normal user.